# How to access adapter's holder.itemview on an activity not linked to that adapter?

Tags: android, adapter

I have an activity named Admin and MainActivity of which I have inflate the adapter and loading data from the database using recyclerView.

On the adminActivity, I have a SwitchCompat.

What I want to do is that, whan I Switch to the "ON" position, students can click on any item on the MainActivity page.. But when its on the "OFF" position, itemclick is off.

But this AdminActivity isnt linked to the adapter rendering the items on the MainActivity..
Is there any way I can access the adapter's holder.itemview without loading the items on the Admin Activity ??

Any help will be much appreciated !!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreference to save the ON/OFF state. While clicking on the items you can check whether the state is ON/OFF. Depending upon that you can add your logic.

Comment: Please, Is there and code sample to show?

Comment: You can go through this https://www.codebrainer.com/blog/sharedpreferences